# Navigation menu problem

Tags: html, css, navigation

Having issue with my navigation.

1. How can I prevent it?
   [image]
   My CSS file looks like that: http://pastie.org/2241255
2. My width is variable because of class "current".When some page is active, class current makes it's link bold (and increases navigation bars width). That's why i can't set exact width to #navbar. How can i center navbar with variable width and fill empty place (look at the right side of the image) with color?

My php file looks like that

http://pastie.org/2241292

THX in advance

Comment: Could you add some html into this question? Also if `#navbar` is a block level element and not floated or absolute then you don't need to specify a width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to modify your CSS to include a 100% width for your header? Assuming your header is the `.sf-menu`:

```
.sf-menu {
  line-height:1.0;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: yes it works. first question solved. Now how can i center nav menu with variable width and fill empty space with bg color?

Comment: @TuralT have you tried text-align center on the `#navbar` ? http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/text-align/

Comment: ok. i filled empty space. `.sf-menu {
 line-height: 1.0;
  width:100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000', endColorstr='#202020'); /* for IE */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000), to(#202020)); /* for webkit browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000,  #202020); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ ;
  
}`

Comment: @turalT It should work on inline-block children? I'm glad you've got an answer though.